# What is the equivalent of the spool command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spool

I know you use the spool command when you are trying to write a report to a file in Oracle SQLplus.

What is the equivalent command in MySQL?

This is my code:

```
set termout off

spool ${DB_ADMIN_HOME}/data/Datareport.log @ ${DB_ADMIN_HOME}/Scripts.Datavalidation/Datareportscript.sql

spool off
exit
```

How can I write it in MySQL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I get what you are asking:

```
mysql dbname < ${DB_ADMIN_HOME}/Scripts.Datavalidation/Datareportscript.sql \
> ${DB_ADMIN_HOME}/data/Datareport.log
```

Use redirection.

Comment: so what command are you suing to spool this information to that directory

Comment: what in this above syntax stands for the spool command in sqlplus?

Comment: @rambokayambo: No, it's not at all equivalent to the SQLPlus `spool` command. It's just a way of redirecting all output sent to STDOUT.  (The SQLPlus `spool` command can be used multiple times, to start and stop output being written to any number of output files.)

Answer (score 14):

In MySQL you need to use the commands **`tee`** & **`notee`**:

```
tee data.txt;
//SQL sentences...
notee;
```

**`tee`**`data.txt` == **`spool`**`data.txt`

**`notee`** == **`spool off`**

Comment: Thanks for the right answer, I confirm it is like that, and the following MySQL documentation supports it. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Answer (score 0):

For the Oracle SQLPlus `spool` command, there is no equivalent in the mysql command line client.

To get output from the mysql command line client saved to a file, you can have the operating system redirect the output to a file, rather than to the display.

In Unix, you use the `>` symbol on the command line. (It seems a bit redundant here to give an example of how to redirect output.)

```
date > /tmp/foo.txt
```

That `>` symbol is basically telling the shell to take what is written to the STDOUT handle and redirect that to the named file (overwriting the file if it exists) if you have privileges.

---

**Q:** is `set pagesize` and `set linesize` used in mysql when you are trying to generate a report?

**A:** No. Those are specific to Oracle SQLPlus. I don't know of any equivalent functionality in the mysql command line client. The mysql command line client has some powerful features when its run in interactive mode (e.g. `pager` and `tee`), but in non-interactive mode, it's an inadequate replacement for SQLPlus.

Comment: sorry i have another question...is setpagesize and setline size used in mysql when you are trying to generate a report? any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: @rambokayambo: no, the mysql command line client does not have any equivalent functionality for the SQLPlus-specific `set pagesize` and `set linesize`