# MySQL: Redirect ouput to logfile from SQL script

Tags: mysql, logfile

I'd like to execute a SQL script file from mysql command line tool, like

```
mysql database < script.sql
```

where the script *script.sql* contains a statement that redirects the output to a file.

I thought this should be possible by placing a *tee* into the script like this:

```
tee script.log;

SELECT sysdate() AS "Start" FROM dual;
UPDATE table SET column = 'off';
COMMIT;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, no *script.log* appears.

Is there any possibility to redirect the output to a file from the script itself?

Use case: These scripts will be executed by our Service Department when deploying the application. They would like to execute the script with as little steps and effort as possible, so placing a redirect (*> script.log*) at the end of the command prompt is  not a real option, at least if they must execute a bunch of scripts at once.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Use OUTFILE as part of SELECT itself as follows:
SELECT * FROM myTable INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.log'. Also, for spoolong, check 
[What is the equivalent of the spool command in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190337/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-spool-command-in-mysql)

Comment: `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` works in SELECTs, only, and tries to create files on the MySQL server. That won't work, I'm affraid.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's the usual solution, but doesn't fit into use case. Anyway, I guess I have to provide a thin wrapper scipt to Sevice Dep...