# How to export a query in mysql to a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, autosave

I want to save the query I wrote in mysql console to a **.sql** file... for example :

"`CREATE TABLE Employee(id...,name...,salary);`"

I want to save the code instead of it's result. 
thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190337/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-spool-command-in-mysql)

Comment: How are you executing this query? On the terminal, through a shell script... How?

Comment: WAMP app---->mysql console

Answer (score 0):

Pass the query in a variable and then execute it. This way, variable will hold the query and you'll be able to do whatever you want:

1. execute it
2. send it to a file
3. any other operation...

> query="CREATE TABLE Employee(id...,name...,salary)";
>
> mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306 -p -e "$query"
>
> echo $query >> query.sql

This'll print the data as well as populate a file `query.sql` in your PWD. The above example is a part of a shell script.

Comment: I just want to have .sql file that's written in it ,say,"CREATE DATABASE Company;"

Comment: But I want to save this file using the mysql console environment

Comment: Happy to help :)
Please accept/upvote it if it serves what you were looking for.

Comment: To avoid printing anything, simply skip the execution part i.e. `mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306 -p -e ""`