# Bash script with multiple queries and redirection in the same mysql session

Tags: mysql, bash

My bash script queries a `mysql` database 3 times and redirects the standard out of each query to a file (3 different files in total with different columns structure ).

I want it to ask for the `mysql` password as it's important for me not to have the password in the script or on disk.

How can I include all queries and stdout redirection in the same `mysql` session in order to avoid asking for the password 3 times?

This is what I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mysql -h database.com -u user -p -e "USE database; mysql query1"  > file1
mysql -h database.com -u user -p -e "USE database; mysql query2"  > file2
mysql -h database.com -u user -p -e "USE database; mysql query3"  > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tee` and `notee` commands and write a single query file, say `queries.sql` and invoke it in a single shot:

```
use database
tee file1
query1
notee
tee file2
query2
notee
tee file3
query3
notee
```

Then invoke it:

```
mysql -h database.com -u user -p -e "source queries.sql" > /dev/null
```

---

Related:

- [What is the equivalent of the spool command in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11190337/6862601)
- [How can I run an SQL script in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8940230/6862601)

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash to prompt for the password, and then supply it to each of the mysql commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter the password for MySQL:"
read -s PASSWD

mysql -h database.com -u user -p$PASSWD -e "USE database; mysql query1"  > file1
mysql -h database.com -u user -p$PASSWD -e "USE database; mysql query2"  > file2
mysql -h database.com -u user -p$PASSWD -e "USE database; mysql query3"  > file3
```

Here is a POSIX-compliant version of silent prompting for non-bash shells:

```
stty -echo
printf "enter the password for MySQL:"
read PASSWD
stty echo
printf "\n"
```