# find original mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am learning mysql.  I created a database with a few tables using mysql workbench. I forgot to save the queries used to create these tables. Can I still find the queries and save them?

Comment: If you used Workbench file and still have it, you can generate SQL queries by running migration again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes all you have to do is run this query with the appropriate table name

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`;
```

the second column displays the actual query ran to create the table

#### EDIT:

Per the OP request if you want to see the insert statements you will have to do a dump
see [**THIS LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978326/get-insert-statement-for-existing-row-in-mysql) for a way to do that

ALSO since you are using workbench you could do it this way

> Open MySQL Workbench > Home > Manage Import / Export (Right bottom) /
> Select Required DB > Advance Exports Options Tab >Complete Insert
> [Checked] > Start Export.

or if its 6.1 > then click the management tab (beside schemas) and choose Data Export

Comment: Thank you. That works wonderfully! But what about the queries other than to create the table? say, used to add values to the tables? how can i retrieve those?

Comment: @fantastic4 see my edit, i added a link to another question that answers that :)

Comment: For related information, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html