# How to backup a table or entire database by query as SQL format

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, mysql-backup, remote-backup

I know that we can backup a table by query as CSV format like this:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/backup'
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But this is creating the backup as CSV format. Is there any way to make it as SQL format ?

Comment: What do you mean by SQL format? Do you want to copy the contents of a table to another table? Or do you want the result to be a series of insert statements? Or what?

Comment: The table needs to be backed up in an sql file as opposed to his current method's csv file. @HoneyboyWilson

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978326/get-insert-statement-for-existing-row-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to export your database and/or tables into an sql file through a query command. You will need to make use of the [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) command-line function.

**Simple export:**

```
mysqldump db_name tbl_name > backup-file.sql;
```

Note that without giving any destination path, your file will be located in the same directory where you performed the dump.

**Export to specified path:**

```
mysqldump db_name tbl_name > C:\"backup"\backup-file.sql;
```

**Simple import:**

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
```

**Import from specified path:**

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source C:\"backup"\backup-file.sql;
```

Using double-quotes `"` around your path is only necessary in case you make use of white spaces in your directory path.

Comment: Thanks for the info but i already know about the mysqldump. I'm just looking for a way of doing the same thing by just using queries. I'm not gonna use any command line interface.

Comment: That's the way to do it if you want an sql file.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be an .sql file. But the contents inside the backup file has to be sql queries. Like you know `INSERT INTO table (column1, ...) VALUES (value1, ...)`.